# -Xmx64m зачем нужны такие ограничения для виртуальной машины?

Tags: jvm

-Xmx64m, -Xms64m, -Xss64m

Подскажите пож-та, для чего нужны такие ограничения при запуске приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Какие бывают типы OutOfMemoryError или из каких частей состоит память java процесса**.

Если вы словили OutOfMemoryError, то это вовсе не значит, что ваше приложение создает много объектов, которые не могут почиститься сборщиком мусора и заполняют всю память, выделенную вами с помощью параметра -Xmx. Я, как минимум, могу придумать два других случая, когда вы можете увидеть эту ошибку. Дело в том, что память java процесса не ограничивается областью -Xmx, где ваше приложение программно создает объекты.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Область памяти, занимаемая java процессом, состоит из нескольких частей. Тип OutOfMemoryError зависит от того, в какой из них не хватило места.

1. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Не хватает место в куче, а именно, в области памяти в которую помещаются объекты, создаваемые программно в вашем приложении. Размер задается параметрами -Xms и -Xmx. Если вы пытаетесь создать объект, а места в куче не осталось, то получаете эту ошибку. Обычно проблема кроется в утечке памяти, коих бывает великое множество, и интернет просто пестрит статьями на эту тему.

2. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Данная ошибка возникает при нехватке места в Permanent области, размер которой задается параметрами -XX:PermSize и -XX:MaxPermSize. Что там лежит и как бороться с OutOfMemoryError возникающей там, я уже описал подробнейшим образом [тут](http://www.javaspecialist.ru/2011/04/permanent.html)

3. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Данная ошибка может возникнуть как при переполнении первой, так и второй областей. Связана она с тем, что памяти осталось мало и GC постоянно работает, пытаясь высвободить немного места. Данную ошибку можно отключить с помощью параметра -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit, но, конечно же, её надо не отключать, а либо решать проблему утечки памяти, либо выделять больше объема, либо менять настройки GC.

4. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Впервые я столкнулся с данной ошибкой несколько лет назад, когда занимался нагрузочным тестированием и пытался выяснить максимальное количество пользователей, которые могут работать с нашим веб-приложением. Я использовал специальную тулзу, которая позволяла логинить пользователей и эмулировать их стандартные действия. На определенном количестве клиентов, я начал получать OutOfMemoryError. Не особо вчитываясь в текст сообщения и думая, что мне не хватает памяти на создание сессии пользователя и других необходимых объектов, я увеличил размер кучи приложения (-Xmx). Каково же было мое удивление, когда после этого количество пользователей одновременно работающих с системой только уменьшилось. Давайте подробно разберемся как же такое получилось.

На самом деле это очень просто воспроизвести на windows на 32-битной машине, так как там процессу выделяется не больше 2Гб.

Допустим у вас есть приложение с большим количеством одновременно работающих пользователей, которое запускается с параметрами -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xss512K. Если всего процессу доступно 2G, то остается свободным еще коло 768M. Именно в данном остатке памяти и создаются стеки потоков. Таким образом, примерно вы можете создать не больше 768*(1024/512)=1536 (у меня при таких параметрах получилось создать 1316) нитей (см. рисунок в начале статьи), после чего вы получите OutOfMemoryError. Если вы увеличиваете -Xmx, то количество потоков, которые вы можете создать соответственно уменьшается. Вариант с уменьшением -Xss, для возможности создания большего количества потоков, не всегда выход, так как, возможно, у вас существуют в системе потоки требующие довольно больших стеков. Например, поток инициализации или какие-нибудь фоновые задачи. Но все же выход есть. Оказывается при программном создании потока, можно указать размер стека: [Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target, String name,long stackSize)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.ThreadGroup,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String,%20long%29). Таким образом вы можете выставить -Xss довольно маленьким, а действия требующие больших стеков, выполнять в отдельных потоках, созданных с помощью упомянутого выше конструктора.

Более подробно, что же лежит в стеке потока, и куда уходит эта память, можно прочитать [тут](http://www.javaspecialist.ru/2011/04/java-thread-stack.html).

Конечно, вам может показаться данная проблема слегка надуманной, так как большинство серверов нынче крутиться на 64-битной архитектуре, но все же считаю данный пример весьма полезным, так как он помогает разобраться из каких частей состоит память java-процесса.

[Взято из статьи на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/117274/)

Answer (score 1):

Вот, нашёл ответ

> -Xms size in bytes Sets the initial size of the Java heap.  The default size is 2097152 (2MB).  The values must be a multiple of, and
>   greater than, 1024 bytes (1KB). (The -server flag increases the
>   default size to 32M.)
>
> -Xmn size in bytes Sets the initial Java heap size for the Eden generation.  The default value is 640K.  (The -server flag increases
>   the default size to 2M.)
>
> -Xmx size in bytes Sets the maximum size to which the Java heap can grow.  The default size is 64M.  (The -server flag increases the
>   default size to 128M.)  The maximum heap limit is ab
>
> out 2 GB (2048MB).

Comment: *The maximum heap limit is about 2 GB (2048MB).* - какая-то очень устаревшая документация, сейчас точно можно поставить 32, и это не предел